# Time format is changing from(hh:mm:ss) to number

Tags: lightning-aura-components, time

I have created a custom field of time datatype. I am using this custom field in my lightning component.
It is displayed in number.

`<lightning:input type="Time" value="{!d.Sign_Out__c}" timeStyle="medium" format="h:mm:ss a/>`

[image]

when I try to save it is getting saved but in the UI it is immediately changing the time to numbers and displayed. It is showing the error as"Your entry does not match the allowed format h:mm:ss a".
Can anyone help me on this issue.  TIA

Comment: what's type in back-end. Because I can see Sign-In is showing perfect way.

Comment: I just hardcoded the field Sign-In and checked if it is showing correctly or not. The backend type is Time.